# Is it possible to programmatically find upstream publishers with Reactor 3.0?

Tags: project-reactor

Given a list of Fluxes, I'd like to determine which are upstream of others in the list and which aren't. A way to get upstream publishers for each flux would do the trick, but I'm open to other suggestions.

Also, is it possible to detect circular dependencies between fluxes? I'd like to only allow the creation of DAGs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a best effort way (not 100% supported) with the `Scannable` interface:

```
Flux<T> fluxToCheck;
List<Flux> potentialParents;

Scannable s = Scannable.from(fluxToCheck);
Stream<Scannable> parents = s
    .parents() //this is the important part
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

potentialParents.retainAll(parents);
//or some more efficient other tests on the collections
```

`Scannable#parents()` recursively looks up `Scannable` that advertise a `PARENT`, which I reckon most Reactor core operators should do.

`Scannable.from(foo)` returns a NO-OP `Scannable` if the object you pass is not actually `Scannable`.